# Watson assistant instance loading failed

Tags: watson-assistant

I have a plus trial  instance of  watson assistant created . but immediately launch the service, a pop up showing "Error : Instances could not be loaded at this time" appears in the window and so no instance of discovery service is showing  in the "add search skill" option of watson assistant, even i have discovery service created in the same region.

Comment: welcome .. improve question quality , refer this link `https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask`

Answer (score 0):

This could be a glitch from IBM Cloud sometimes.

Possible Solutions:

1. Try opening the same URL in the incognito mode
2. Try to check if there is any issue from IBM Cloud in the link: https://cloud.ibm.com/status